# Call to undefined function error after adding add_filter to wp-config

Tags: filters, errors, wp-config

I am getting

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_filter() in example.com/wp-config.php on line 20
```

after adding

```
add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_true' );
```

to wp-config.php

My plugins.php file is present and add_filter() is defined inside of it.

I just want to enable automatic updates for core, plugins and thems.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a section that should look like this:

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php' );
```

`add_filter()` is available **after** that, you are probably using it too early.

Comment: That's it, thanks! The Automatic Background Updates Wordpress codex entry (http://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates) should probably be updated with this info, but I have no idea how.

Comment: @SkyHiRider I made that update. :) You need an account on wordpress.org to edit the wiki pages.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended best practice is to use a `mu-plugin` for this. Adding `add_filter()`s to `wp-config.php` directly can cause all kinds of other problems and conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I used wp-cli and got this error.

I had in wp-config.php at bottom:

```
remove_filter('template_redirect','redirect_canonical');
```

instead i put to top

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');

define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

it solved my problem